# Kali Linux freezes after I log in, but not if I log into root first and then switch user

Tags: kali-linux, usermod

I recently changed the default kali username and password via following a tutorial that used usermod commands. However, after logging back into the newly named account, the screen freezes on the wallpaper and is not responsive. However, if I boot up my PC and log into the root user first and then switch user into my new account it works fine. The issue only occurs when I try to log into the account directly.

I'm very new to Linux so I'm pretty confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I'm very new to Linux .." => mandatory Kali documentation link: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ "it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux". Beside you didn't tell what you did, you didn't even put the "following tutorial" (you should put the commands done, not only the link to the tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Because we don't know what you did it is almost impossible to give a serious answer. @A.B already introduced the harsh reality that Kali is not for the uninitiated. It requires a lot of knowledge, ans Unix/LInux is ust a part of that.

For your immediate problem, you may, as root, to `chown -R <new user> /home/<dirname>`